# Problem making appear the custom ribbon - Outlook 365

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-addin

I need your help. I am new creating VSTOs. This code works and it creates my XML, such as I want it. However, the ribbon and the button do not get to show in my outlook. I am using OUTLOOK 365 ProPlus

My Idea is when the user clicks the custom button which is located on the custom ribbon; the email selected got save into an XML file. "This is my goal"

Here is the code

This is my class to call Outlook

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        XMLFileCreation xmlfile = new XMLFileCreation();
        Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;



        // public ThisAddIn()
        //{

        //}

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.button1.Checked = true;
            currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
            currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);

        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder selectedFolder =
                this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
            try
            {
                if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
                {
                        Object seleObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
                        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (seleObject as Outlook.MailItem);
                        string Subject= mailItem.Subject.ToString();
                        string TO= mailItem.To.ToString();
                        string Body=mailItem.Body.ToString();
                        string SenderEmail=mailItem.SenderEmailAddress.ToString();
                        string SenderName=mailItem.SenderName .ToString();
                        xmlfile.CreateXMLFile(Subject, TO, SenderName, SenderEmail, Body);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
            #region VSTO generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

With this class, I called to create an XML file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
    class XMLFileCreation
    {

        public void CreateXMLFile(string Subject, string TO, string SenderName,string SenderEmail,string Body)
        {
            XmlTextWriter xWrite = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\Desktop\\Outloot-Marketing\\Marketing.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            xWrite.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xWrite.WriteStartElement("Email");
            xWrite.WriteStartElement("TO");
            xWrite.WriteString(TO);
            xWrite.WriteEndElement();
            xWrite.WriteStartElement("FROM");
            xWrite.WriteString(SenderName);
            xWrite.WriteEndElement();
            xWrite.WriteStartElement("SENDER_EMAIL");
            xWrite.WriteString(SenderEmail);
            xWrite.WriteEndElement();
            xWrite.WriteStartElement("SUBJECT");
            xWrite.WriteString(Subject);
            xWrite.WriteEndElement();
            xWrite.WriteStartElement("EMAIL_BODY");
            xWrite.WriteString(Body);
            xWrite.WriteEndElement();
            xWrite.WriteEndElement();
            xWrite.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

With this class, I am trying to create the ribbon and the botton 
My idea is when the user clicks on the botton the email selected will be saved as an XML file. However, I have not been successful in display the ribbon in my outlook. I need help displaying the ribbon and the botton as well. I will appreciate any help fro you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;

namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {

        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            //  ThisAddIn mainapp = new ThisAddIn();
            if (((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello from the else");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That empty catch block is gonna make it hard to fix any errors.

Comment: Could somebody help me?